# How do I add data from a column in 2d array into a database

Tags: c#, sql

I need help.
My task is to scan CSV files and add data to the already created table inside database. But there is a catch: I need to scan the first row, so I know what I am adding and then I need data below each parameter item add to the corresponding property inside the table.

I need to add: "Jmeno" = name, "Prijmeni" = lastname, "Titul" = title, and email.

I am using Microsoft SQL management server 2017.

Here is the screen of my table + what I got in it already:

[image: My Table] [Database/Imputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZQl.png)

I have already done the scanning of the first row (at least I hope so) and then I created 2D array list, but now I have a dilemma: how do I add data from columns in the under row and under the parameter I want? Here is a code I have created until this point:

```
        private void importCSVButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) //ms: enable null options in prijmeni SQL
    {
        string jmeno;
        string prijmeni;
        string titul;
        string email;
        List<List<string>> x = new List<List<string>>();
        try
        {
            
            OpenFileDialog browseDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            browseDialog.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(browseDialog.FileName);

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                List<string> row = new List<string>();
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(';');
                string firstvalue = values.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                firstvalue = Akro.Helpers.String.RemoveDiacritics(firstvalue);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    row.Add(values[i]);
                }
                x.Add(row);


                /*
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(';');
                string firstline = values.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                firstline = Akro.Helpers.String.RemoveDiacritics(firstline);
                
                 string[] values = line.Split(';');

                 string[] firstline = values.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                
                */


                for (int i = 1; i > values.Length; i++)
                {
                    TOsoby person = new TOsoby();

                    if (x[0][i] == "jmeno")
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                        {
                            x[j, 0].
                        }
                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "name")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "firstname")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "prijmeni")
                    {
                       
                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "surname")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "lastname")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "familyname")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "titul")
                    {
                       
                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "title")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "email")
                    {
                        
                    }
                    else if (x[0][i] == "")
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                        else
                        {
                            Exception ex = new Exception();
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unknown header! Please use standard header like: (jmeno, prijmeni, surname, name, firstname).", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                            Console.Write(ex);
                        }
                }
            }
            

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do that please?

Comment: Show us the SQL too.

Comment: What database are you using?  You need to use an INSERT statement to put data into the database.